# Test Driven Development process

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I have read so many tutorials on TDD but still confused to decide what's best way to start with TDD.
There are two ways to get start with TDD

1) Should TDD test cases start before implementing your Scenario or coding. In this way, you write first test case and generate all the code from that test case like classes, methods etc

2) Should TDD be done when you finish your coding?

Answer (score 0):

TDD is Test-First Programming. You should write test before any implementation. From simplest to more advanced scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To gain the most value out of TDD you should be writing your tests first.  A good starting point is to follow Uncle Bob's 3 rules of TDD.

http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd

TDD can be seen as a thinking tool that helps you flesh out your ideas and design.

Answer (score 0):

If the tests are writen after the production code, they are not driving it. It can only be TDD if the test is written first, then the production code.